# How to prevent a DOM show using jQuery

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-deferred

Is there any methods to prevent a DOM in jQM show until data is ready loaded? I have two pages, need to get data from JSON and i don't want to show them when data haven't ready loaded into them. And here is what i did but it not work. I have two page #palvelu and #varaus in index.html file.

```
    var varausJarru = $.Deferred();
    var palveluJarru = $.Deferred();
$( document ).on("pagecreate", "#varaus", function () {
        getJson();
        varausJarru;
    });
    $( document ).on("pagecreate", "#palvelu", function () {
        getPalveluJson();
        palveluJarru;
    });
    $( document ).on("pageshow", "#palvelu", function () {
     palveluJarru.resolve("http://localhost:63342/Nails/www/index.html#palvelu");
    });
   $( document ).on("pageshow", "#varaus", function () {
        varausJarru.resolve("http://localhost:63342/Nails/www/index.html#varaus");
    });
```

Maybe i wrote something wrong?!

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){})` might help you out but i am not to sure. Because i had a similar problem. I just build in a **loadingspinner** that is visibile until everything is loaded using `$(window).on(load)` together with a `setTimeout()`

Comment: It not work bro, anyway thanks.

Comment: @ThịnhKều: i'm not able to understand the flow of your navigation. Maybe on("pageshow") is too late to wait for the json,Could you create a fiddle? I'ill try to help you.

Comment: Exactly! showpage is too late and json data must be got from device on ready. Anyway i've resolved this problem, thanks bro.